# need help selecting only cases with all children having a closed date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know the title is confusing but I need help determining which court cases have all the children associated with that case having a programClosureDate.
I can run this query:

```
CaseInfo Table
CaseID,
CaseNumber,
CaseName

CaseChild Table
CaseID,           FK to CaseInfo
ChildPartyID, FK to PartyID in Party table
ProgramClosureDate

Party Table
ID,
PartyID,
Firstname,
LastName

SELECT           ci.CaseNumber, ci.CaseName, p.firstname+' '+p.lastname AS child, 
                 ci.programClosureDate
FROM             CaseInfo ci JOIN
                 CaseChild cc ON ci.CaseID = cc.CaseID JOIN
                 Party p ON cc.ChildPartyID = p.PartyID

WHERE            cc.ProgramClosureDate IS NOT NULL                    
ORDER BY         ci.CaseName
```

But this just gives me the children that have programClosureDate IS NOT NULL.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Andy

Comment: What version of sql server, from 2008 onwards you could use the all keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gets you the cases where all the children have a closure date.

```
select CaseId
from CaseChild cc
group by CaseId
having count(*) = count(cc.ProgramClosureDate)
```

It is using a little trick . . . `count(*)` is the number of records in each case and `count(cc.ProgramCLosureDate)` is the number of non-NULL closure dates.  These are the same when all cases are closed.

If you want more information, you can join it in:

```
select ci.CaseNumber, ci.CaseName, p.firstname+' '+p.lastname AS child, 
       ci.programClosureDate
from (select CaseId
      from CaseChild cc
      group by CaseId
      having count(*) = count(cc.ProgramClosureDate)
     ) closed join
     CaseInfo ci
     on closed.CaseId = ci.CaseId join
     Party p
     ON cc.ChildPartyID = p.PartyID
order by ci.CaseName
```

The above subquery is used to define the population for the rest of the query.

Comment: This work great!!  Thanks for explaining the Count() expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this WHERE condition

```
Where CaseID not in (Select CaseID  from CaseChild ProgramClosureDate IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach...
I'm not sure about performance on the different methods suggested, best to test.

```
;WITH OpenCases AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CaseID
    FROM CaseChild
    WHERE ProgramClosureDate IS NULL
)
SELECT   ci.CaseNumber
        ,ci.CaseName
        ,child  = p.firstname+' '+p.lastname
        ,ci.programClosureDate
FROM CaseInfo   ci 
JOIN CaseChild  cc  ON ci.CaseID = cc.CaseID
JOIN OpenCases  oc  ON ci.CaseID != oc.CaseID
JOIN Party      p   ON cc.ChildPartyID = p.PartyID
WHERE cc.ProgramClosureDate IS NOT NULL                    
ORDER BY ci.CaseName
```